# Why is ReSharper showing unused variables as an error in only one of my projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I'm working on a C# solution that I inherited from another developer, and it was last worked on in 2011. He created it in VS2010 Professional, and swears he's never used ReSharper. I'm using VS2012 Pro and ReSharpher 7.1.3.

The solution has 7 projects total (3 winforms, 3 class libraries, and 1 console application), and in the console application, ReSharper is flagging any unused variable as an error, and I'm not sure why. It should be noted that the project compiles just fine, and VS' error output shows nothing in regards to the unused variables.

Initially, I thought that it was linked to the variable type that was not being used, but this proved false. I've tried several different variable types, all with the same effect.

So now I'm thinking that it has to be a project-specific setting, but the only three setting layers I have show that "Unused local variable" should appear as a warning.

I'm at a loss as to what is causing this to show up as an error. The obvious solution is to remove or use the unused variable, but I would also like to be certain that there is nothing else going on behind the scenes that I'm not aware of.

EDIT:
A few examples of the unused variables:

```
List<string> keys = Dependencies.Keys.ToList();
string testString = "test";
int testInt = 0;
```

Edit 2:
The above three variables are only declared and instantiated locally within a method, but never used anywhere in the rest of the code. I receive the following if I suppress the warning:

```
#pragma warning disable 168
        List<string> keys = Dependencies.Keys.ToList();
#pragma warning restore 168
```

Restarting ReSharper did nothing to correct this.

Comment: With the little lightbulb, when you do "Suppress Inspection" > "Inspections options for [...]", in the "Inspection Options" window that pops up, it's really only at "Warning"?

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault That's correct. If I suppress it, this is the auto generated code: 

    #pragma warning disable 168

Comment: Hm, is it like that from the start, or it started randomly? You could still try to restart ReSharper (Tools > Options > ReSharper > Suspend), but I doubt it'll solve the issue. That's quite weird.

Comment: You have three Re# settings - local (for your computer), local (for your project) and team (for your project). If three does not exist, go to two. if two does not exist, go to one. Could you check all three settings and make sure that they are configured correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing your project has warnings set to errors.

Go to the following menu options

Project >Properties > Build

On the right hand side below "Errors and warnings" you will see

**"Treat warnings as errors"**

This is a project based setting and would not have anything to do with if the previous user had resharper or not. It is something that resharper reads off of though as stated here : [ReSharper web help](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Code_Highlighting.html)

> Note
>
> In Visual Studio project settings, you can choose to treat warnings as
>   errors. ReSharper is aware of this option and highlights warnings
>   accordingly: if this setting is on, then issues that correspond to
>   compiler warnings will be highlighted as errors.
>
> This setting is configurable in the project properties: Project |
>   [Project Name] Properties | Treat warnings as errors and can be
>   applied to all warnings if All is selected or to the specified
>   warnings only.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I had to restart ReSharper in order for the change to take effect. Didn't even realize the project had been set up this way, and didn't consider checking this.